# Mistaken identity of "Rabbi Chanina" in some siddurim

Tags: jewish-books, prayer-book, mistakes, maseches-shabbos, kabbalat-shabbat

In the Kabbalas Shabbos service, which concludes with "*Omar Rabbi Elozor*," the previous paragraph is taken from [Shabbos 12a](http://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.12a.4?lang=bi).

> תניא חנניא אומר חייב אדם למשמש בבגדו ע"ש עם חשכה אמר רב יוסף הלכתא רבתי לשבת.‏

I've found in Israel, that *Rinat Yisroel*, *Tefillat Kol Peh*, *Koren*, and even the famous *Shloh Siddur* commence with "*Tanya omar Rabbi Chanina*," instead of "*Rabbi Chananya*."

Why do they make this apparent mistake?

Comment: stuart plaskow, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks for bringing your question here! I fixed up the formatting of your question. For future reference, please avoid using all-caps, as it's distracting and hard to read, and stick to standard written English grammar. I hope you'll stick around and check out the rest of Mi Yodeya, perhaps starting with our other [tag:kabbalat-shabbat] questions.

Comment: Maybe the Siddur is right and the Gemara is wrong?

Comment: Are you implying that there are not variational differences between various manuscripts of the Gemara, depending on when and where they were written? Maybe one manuscript might say "Tanya omar Rabbi Chanina" and another "Rabbi Chanina", and it's up to the publisher/nusach to determine which to use.

Comment: I googled תניא חנניא אומר חייב אדם למשמש בבגדו ע"ש עם חשכה אמר רב יוסף הלכתא רבתי לשבת.‏ and was asked "Did you mean: תניא חנינא אומר חייב אדם למשמש בבגדו ע"ש עם חשכה אמר רב יוסף הלכתא רבתי לשבת" but all the references were to חנניא!

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Sefaria's Siddur text has the version stuart's asking about http://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz,_Shabbat,_Kabbalat_Shabbat,_Bameh_Madlikin.8?lang=bi